# Is there any mathematical model to estimate the actual number of cases of Covid-19 giving the testing strategy used by authorities?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I saw on the news that NY City has more cases per capita than Italy. But this is looking only to confirmed cases. I would like to be able to compare the numbers of cases in places using different strategies to test the population. What would be a good model to compare, say, NY City with Milan or Seul?

Answer (score 3):

If testing was more easily available, a sensible thing to do would be to go out and test random samples of the population.  Unfortunately this is likely not feasible in the current situation.